# How to access a child class's overridden class property in a base class's method? '__class__' still point to the base class

Tags: python

I want to create a set of class to manage different configuration arguments for different experiments. I want to set a list of attributes as the class attribute for each class to check if the attributes given is exactly needed.

To save codes, I write a general `__init__` and wish it could apply to derived classes and use the derived class's `_attr_` to do the checking work.

I use `__class__` to refer to the current class but it seems to point to the base class.

Here are some codes. The `__init__` function that BCDConfig inherent insists that `_class__` should be the class where it is defined in -- ExpConfig.

```py
import json

class ExpConfig:
    _attr_ = ['attr1', 'attr2']   # list of string

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = {}

        # only take defined attributes
        for key in config:
            if key in __class__._attr_:
                self.config[key] = config[key]
            else:
                raise ValueError

        # check if there is anything undefined
        for key in __class__._attr_:
            assert key in self.config, "Missing arguments!"

    def save_config(self, path):
        with open(path, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.config, f)

    @classmethod
    def load_config(cls, path):
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            config = json.load(f)
        exp_config = __class__(config)
        return exp_config


class BCDConfig(ExpConfig):

    _attr_ = ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']

    def __init__(self, config):
        super(BCDConfig, self).__init__(config)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bcd_config1 = BCDConfig({'attr1':123, 'attr2':444})
    bcd_config1.save_config('./bcd1.cfg')
    print(BCDConfig.load_config('./bcd1.cfg').config)

    bcd_config2 = BCDConfig({'attr1':1253, 'attr2':4344, 'attr3':1})
    bcd_config2.save_config('./bcd2.cfg')
    print(BCDConfig.load_config('./bcd2.cfg'))
```

Here is the output. I wonder if there's a way other than `__class__` that can be interpreted dynamically to the derived class. Thank you for any help!

```
{'attr1': 123, 'attr2': 444}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MysriO/Documents/Local Codes/DEAP_Ricotta/exp_config.py", line 46, in <module>
    bcd_config2 = BCDConfig({'attr1':1253, 'attr2':4344, 'attr3':1})
  File "C:/Users/MysriO/Documents/Local Codes/DEAP_Ricotta/exp_config.py", line 37, in __init__
    super(BCDConfig, self).__init__(config)
  File "C:/Users/MysriO/Documents/Local Codes/DEAP_Ricotta/exp_config.py", line 14, in __init__
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

Comment: i think you need to change `__class__` to `self.__class__`

Comment: I don't see `ExpConfig` inheriting from any other class in order for `__class__` to point to its BaseClass

Answer (score 4):

`__class__` is only ever going to point to the class that you defined the method on. It's *purpose* is not to change with subclasses.

Use the [`type()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type), (e.g. `type(self)`), if you want to get the class of the current instance. This returns `self.__class__` in this case, but know that `type()` knows how to handle different types of objects, not just Python classes. It may be that you meant to use `self.__class__` all along.

I'd not use `__class__` unless you specifically want to access the class object on which a method was defined, ignoring inheritance, and then only with an explicit comment explaining why you do this. The `__class__` closure is not widely known and not intended for general use.

From the [reference documentation on class creation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object):

> `__class__` is an implicit closure reference created by the compiler if any methods in a class body refer to either `__class__` or `super`. This allows the zero argument form of `super()` to correctly identify the class being defined based on lexical scoping, while the class or instance that was used to make the current call is identified based on the first argument passed to the method.

For the `load_config` classmethod, you already have a reference to the class: use `cls` there, not `__class__`.

Next, you don't actually *need* the class reference in `__init__`. You could use `self._attr_` instead; class attributes are accessible via the instance, provided there are no instance attributes shadowing them:

```
class ExpConfig:
    _attr_ = ['attr1', 'attr2']   # list of string

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = {}

        # only take defined attributes
        for key in config:
            if key in self._attr_:
                self.config[key] = config[key]
            else:
                raise ValueError

        # check if there is anything undefined
        for key in self._attr_:
            assert key in self.config, "Missing arguments!"
```

The `self._attr_` reference will find the `_attr_` attribute on the correct class for the given instance:

```
>>> class ExpConfig:
...     _attr_ = ['attr1', 'attr2']
...
>>> class BCDConfig(ExpConfig):
...     _attr_ = ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']
...
>>> ExpConfig()._attr_
['attr1', 'attr2']
>>> BCDConfig()._attr_
['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']
```

I'd actually make `_attr_` a [*set* object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), not a list. Attribute names must be unique, don't need a specific order, and sets are optimised for membership testing and intersections. If you combine a set with [dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) you can quickly test for missing and extraneous keys:

```
class ExpConfig:
    _attr_ = frozenset(('attr1', 'attr2'))   # immutable set of strings

    def __init__(self, config):
        extra = config.keys() - self.attrs
        if extra:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid config keys: {', '.join(extra)}")
        missing = self.attrs - config.keys()
        if missing:
            raise ValueError(f"Missing config keys: {', '.join(missing)}")

        self.config = config.copy()

    def save_config(self, path):
        with open(path, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.config, f)

    @classmethod
    def load_config(cls, path):
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            config = json.load(f)
        return cls(config)
```

I used a `frozenset()` object, an immutable set, because you probably don't want to alter the attribute names after creating your class. A `frozenset()` will protect you from accidental bugs that do so anyway.

Finally, subclasses can re-use definitions from a parent class with the [set union operator `|`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union), so `BCDConfig` could be defined as:

```
class BCDConfig(ExpConfig):
    _attr_ = ExpConfig._attr_ | frozenset(('attr3',))
```

Comment: I'd like to add for readers: 1. You can also use `self.__class__`, which is pretty much equivalent to `type(self)` and is probably what OP is thinking of. The variable `__class__` is almost never what users want to use. 2. `self._attr_` will also work.

Comment: @AlexHall: I always prefer API functions like `type()` over accessing dunder names directly.

Comment: That's fine, I'm pointing it out so that OP can understand their mistake better.